# Excel Delimiter Splitting

Tags: asp.net

I have an excel file and I am splitting cell content based on special charectors as shown below:

```
dt =new DataTable(); 
dt.Columns.Add("Name"); 
dt.Columns.Add("Age"); 
dt.Columns.Add("Skills"); 
dt.Columns.Add("counts");

string name = rdr[0].ToString(); 
string age = rdr[1].ToString();

char[] s = new char[1] { ';' }; 
char[] k=new char[1] {'@'};

string[] skills = rdr[2].ToString().Split(s); 
string[] counts = rdr[3].ToString().Split(k);
```

(ie) If i have below table

Name           kk

Age             31

Skills              .net;sqlserver;oracle

counts                   1@2@3@

**output will be :**

kk    31     .net                  1

```
          sql                  2

          oracle               3
```

I am successfull in achieveing above output.

**Required Output1:**

if you have 1@# 2@# 3@# in counts column instead of 1@2@3@,the how do i split below expression?

char[] k=new char[1] {'@'};

**Required Output2:**

how to split expression (char[] k=new char[1] {'@'}; 
   ---> if i have both @# and @ (ie) like: 1@# 2@ 3@ in 'counts' column.

**here also i want output as :**

1

2

3

Hope I am clear.Please help me in sorting this issue.

Thanks,

Kranthi

Answer (score 0):

Do like this:

```
string[] counts = rdr[3].ToString().Replace("@#","@").Split(k);
```